# YACC LEX IF AND ELSE calculator

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I have a question about this code I would like to create a IF / ELSE in YACC and LEX. but I have difficulties to detect the condition and execute the right block (because it's depend on the condition!)

I have to make a calculator that takes into account the IF and ELSE I have added TOKEN.
`expr` allows to evaluate an expression
`stmt` and `stmtlist` allows nesting.

```
%%
//  US : liste de ... (commande, assignation, expression)
liste : 
    | liste error RC    { yyerrok; yyclearin; code (STOP); return 1;}
    | liste stmtList RC { printf("stmtList\n"); code((instr_t)printExprCode); code (STOP); return 3;}
    | liste cmd   RC    { code (STOP); return 6;}
    ;
//  US : Commande
cmd : 
      opCmd             { code ((instr_t)*($1->U.pFct));}
    | DBG sym           { dbgSymbol($2); }
    ;

// US : Expression algébrique
expr :  ENTIER          { code2((instr_t)intPush, (instr_t)$1);  }
    | REEL              { code2((instr_t)floPush, (instr_t)$1);}
    | IVAR              { code3((instr_t)varPush, (instr_t)$1, (instr_t)varEval);}
    | FVAR              { code3((instr_t)varPush, (instr_t)$1, (instr_t)varEval);}
    | UNDEF
    | PO expr PF        { printf("test&\n, $$=%f"); $$=$2; }
    | expr opAlg expr   { code ((instr_t)*($2->U.pFct)); }
    | SUB expr          { code((instr_t)negate); } %prec UNARY_MINUS
    | PREDEF PO expr PF { code2((instr_t)predef, (instr_t)$1); }
    | PO ENTIER LT ENTIER PF    { code3((instr_t)intPush, (instr_t)$1, (instr_t)intPush);}
    | expr opCOMP expr  { code ((instr_t)*($2->U.pFct)); }
    
    ;
assgn :
      IVAR AFF expr     { code3((instr_t)varPush, (instr_t)$1, (instr_t)varAssign); }
    | FVAR  AFF expr    { code3((instr_t)varPush, (instr_t)$1, (instr_t)varAssign); }
    | UNDEF AFF expr    { code3((instr_t)varPush, (instr_t)$1, (instr_t)varAssign); }
    ;

//  US : Statement
cond :  PO expr PF { printf("Condition");} ;

//cond :    PO ENTIER LT ENTIER PF { printf("ok"); if($1<$3){$$=1;}else{$$=0;}};

stmt : expr 
    | assgn
    | IF expr stmt {$$ = code(IF,)}
    ;   

//  US : Statement List
stmtList :              {data_t d; d.value = 0; push(d);}
    | stmt
    | stmtList DEL stmtList
    | AO stmtList AF
    ;

//  US : Statement List
block :
     AO stmtList AF         
    ;

// US : sym, nbr, var, opAlg, opCmc
sym : nbr | var | PREDEF | opAlg | opCmd | opCOMP
    ;
nbr : ENTIER | REEL
    ;
var : UNDEF |  IVAR | FVAR 
    ;
opAlg : ADD | SUB | MUL | DIV  
    ;
opCmd : PR_TS | PR_TS2 | DBG_TS | DBG_TS2
    ;
opCOMP : LT | GT | EQ | NE
    ;
%%
```

Comment: Most interpreters do not execute things directly in yacc because of this reason.

Comment: Hi do you have any idea to do this ?

Comment: Not directly within yacc

Comment: Remember that the design you should be using is in stages, and that putting code like this in the wrong stage can massively complicate things.

Comment: Hi tadman How I can simplify my code ?

Comment: It's not a matter of simplifying, it's a matter of putting the right code in the right place. I haven't used this stack in a long time because there are other options that give you more flexibility, like [Ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/) and others. A lot has happened in the last 50 years, Yacc dates from the 1970s, so it might be worth looking at alternatives.

Comment: The easiest option is to build a parse tree, then when the parse is complete, evaluate the tree. It doesn't really matter what kind of parser generator is used.

Comment: No it's my own code , I create parse tree , I have my function pop and push

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for this you'll want an "embedded" action in the middle of the rule.  Something like:

```
stmt: IF expr {
          // generate code to branch to a label if the preceeding expression was false
      } stmtList {
          // generate the label that is branched to
      }
```

You can communicate between these two fragments by setting `$$` to something in the first action and then using that value (as `$3`) in the second action.  The final action needs to set `$$` for the final result of the rule.

For an IF/ELSE, you need something more complex with two labels (one at the end and one just after the ELSE) and two branches (conditional to the else label as with the simple if and unconditional to the end label just before the else label)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I have to give which type to $$.At this time I was able to  push the result of my condition for example 1<2 => 1 , 1>2 => 0 . This value is pushed into the pile.